# PHP Url Encoding Not Encoding Properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, utf-8

I am trying to encode the following string: `Peôn`

Accordiing to: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ the string should enocde to: `Pe%C3%B4n`

When I use `urlencode($name)` I get `Pe%F4n`

SOOOO Lost on this.

I am trying to use the encoded string in the following manner:

Fails:

> http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/Kil%27jaeden/Pe%F4n?fields=statistics

Works:

> http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/Kil%27jaeden/Pe%C3%B4n?fields=statistics

mycode:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['name']);
$name = urlencode($name);
```

EDIT:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$realm = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['realm']);
$locale = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['locale']);
$toon = query_blizz_toon($name, $realm, $locale);

function query_blizz_toon($name, $realm, $locale){  
    $realm = urlencode(stripslashes($realm));
    $name = urlencode($name);
    $q = 'http://'.$locale.'.battle.net/api/wow/character/'.$realm.'/'.$name.'?fields=statistics';
    echo $q;
    $character = @file_get_contents($q);
    $character = json_decode($character);
    return $character;
}
```

`echo $q` ouputs: `http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/Kil%27jaeden/Pe%F4n?fields=statistics`

Still getting the wrong encoding even without the escaping... :/

EDIT:

According to this site: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

`%F4` is the correct encoding for `ô` ...

Comment: Why are you using mysqli_real_escape_string here?

Comment: The name variable is coming from a form with a text input field.

Comment: I don_t know what you di wrong, but your example wirks for me. used tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urlencode – floww just now edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well i am getting exactly what you are expected to get.  Your **`mysqli_real_escape`** is the culprit here. Remove it.

Also, make use of **`Prepared Statements`**, so that you don't have to focus on escaping and stuff.

```
<?php
$name = 'Peôn';
echo $name = urlencode($name);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Pe%C3%B4n
```

Comment: Will move to prepared statements. Still getting the wrong encoding without the escaping. Posted full code above.

Comment: Same results :/. I had initially tried that before asking here on SO. calling `urlencode()` or `rawurlencode()` before the `query_blizz_toon()` call produces `Pe%F4n` aswell.

Comment: I ran the following code alone in its own file: `$name = 'Peôn'; echo $name = urlencode($name);` output: `Pe%F4n`

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape` has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = rawurlencode(utf8_encode($name));
```

Does the trick. Wish i knew why...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the page that has the form.

The web browser is sending the user input encoded in latin-1, but you want it to send UTF-8. One way to fix that is sending the Content-Type header to tell the browser that the page is in UTF-8, if you can't do that you can use the HTML meta tag to do the same, yet another is declaring the `accept-charset` in the form tag.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="...
```

Comment: Setting the Content-Type header made no difference. I did not get to check the accept-charset for the form, but the answer I posted did resolve the issue. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: The appropriate fix is making the browser use UTF-8 encoding to send the form. What you post in your answer helps with the symptoms, i.e. it converts the latin1-encoded text into UTF-8, but if there's any chance the user will send something that cannot be encoded in latin1, such as Russian or Japanese, you will continue having problems.

Comment: In my application I will most likely run into said situation where I have Russian or Japanese characters sent, so I will look into your solution and change the selected answer should it solve the issue.